# MagentoStudy_News exstension - Can't launch Magento custom extension - 404

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

this questions might seem trivial but couldn't find any other resource for the discussion/help on this topic.

I've been developing a custom News component for Magento following "Magento Extension Developers Guide v1.0"

So far I have written the frontend part following the guide.

And now I wish to see the results. As far as I can understand the frontend should be working.

and I know according to config.xml file (this particular piece):

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <gott_news>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Gott_News</module>
                    <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </gott_news>
        </routers>
```

my component should be accessible through: `http://127.0.0.1/magento/news`

and far as my controller's name is `IndexController.php` and there I have `indexAction()` it should automatically run `http://127.0.0.1/magento/news/index/index` but instead of it I'm just getting `404 Not Found 1` in the header of the browser and `Whoops, our bad...` on the page.

Can you explain why the extension isn't working and how to launch Magento's extension? Maybe I have to register this extension somewhere else then in module's magentostudy_news.xml?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Hristo Ivanov - Yes I did, on the same day. I needed to change some tag in configuration file. Gott_News i changed to gottnews or smth like that. I'm sorry but I don't really remember the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/news/
```

> and use die in your indexAction()

Comment: I deleted the whole extension and I'm building it from the beginning following book Magento PHP Developers Guide, gonna follow both this book and the official guide and hopefully I'll build extension that works. And btw, I tried '/index.php/' in between but it didn't work, but I didn't try die();

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try this module that helps you to create new modules
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html

After you have created your module you can investigate and study it.

Filippo